# Dropdown menu in python

Tags: python, kivy

I found this code online but it's not working. here the link:https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/menu/index.html#menu-with-mdtoolbar

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

KV = '''
<IconListItem>

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon


MDScreen

    MDTextField:
        id: field
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: "200dp"
        hint_text: "Password"
        on_focus: if self.focus: app.menu.open()
'''

class IconListItem(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()


class Test(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        menu_items = [
            {
                "viewclass": "IconListItem",
                "icon": "git",
                "height": dp(56),
                "text": f"Item {i}",
                "on_release": lambda x=f"Item {i}": self.set_item(x),
            } for i in range(5)]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.screen.ids.field,
            items=menu_items,
            position="bottom",
            width_mult=4,
        )

    def set_item(self, text__item):
        self.screen.ids.field.text = text__item
        self.menu.dismiss()

    def build(self):
        return self.screen


Test().run()
```

What I need is to choose an element from a list and write it on the label that is exactly what the guide was expected to do.
I'm using python 3.8

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Please provide a [mre] including expected behaviour and actual behaviour.

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?  We expect you to at least look up the error message and try to trace the offending values within your program.
Most of all, please explain *exactly* what you don't understand from the output you get when you trace this code. Include that trace in your MRE.

Comment: The way that you posted this suggests that you want us to figure out what you want to do, and make this code -- which is simply copied from elsewhere, not your own work -- do whatever it is you have in mind.  If so, your question would be very much off-topic.  Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Install development version from master branch

`pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip`